# Processing large amount of files with lynx/grep. Help needed!

Tags: grep, lynx

Can someone please help me with this. it worked perfectly for a second now it creates empty files or no files at all, or only prints the first link and not the remaining ones. don't know what is going on.

i run 
"sudo sh ./doimdb"

and the "doimdb" text file contains:

```
sudo lynx -dump http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182576 > $RANDOM.txt
sudo lynx -dump http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182576 > $RANDOM.txt
sudo lynx -dump http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182576 > $RANDOM.txt

sudo grep -A 20 -r Storyline &> results.txt
```

Comment: I've corrected the formatting, so we can see it clearly. (The edit will take a while to come through). You can have as many links as you like in a code block.

Comment: @steeldriver `grep -r` with no file should recurse the current directory, which is not ideal but should work.

Comment: I've run the script (minus sudo) and it works fine. No idea why it doesn't work for OP.

Answer (score 0):

The main problems with your code are:

- Sudo should only be used when needed. Otherwise you risk creating files you don't have permission to delete, etc.
- Your grep command should only redirect stdout, not stderr: `>` not `&>`.
- Your grep command should only reference the correct input files, not recurse the current directory.

Correct code:

```
#!/bin/bash

lynx -dump http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182576 > dl-$RANDOM.txt
lynx -dump http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182576 > dl-$RANDOM.txt
lynx -dump http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0182576 > dl-$RANDOM.txt

grep -A 20  Storyline dl-*.txt> results.txt
```

Comment: It works. but lynx only prints the first link not the other two. And the actual "dl-$RANDOM.txt" and only one fileis created as "dl-.txt" (no random number, which i really don't need if the results.txt shows them, but still)

Comment: if i copy paste and enter every indivicual line in the terminal it works. but used in "doimdb.sh" it doesn't go through all the links, just prints the first one not the rest, and then the grep shows the result.txt for only one title.

Comment: Okay, I've worked it out. You're executing it wrong; add the shebang line `#!/bin/bash` to the top, run `chmod +x doimdb.sh` to make it executable and call it with `./doimdb.sh`, not `sudo sh ./doimdb`.

Comment: Managed to make it.  you are right .  Also I added \ at the end of each command and && at the start of the next one. It works perfectly.

Comment: But now, probably because of the excessive sudo use LibreOffice won't start. Do you have any ideea on how to fix that.?

Comment: when i run libreoffice, i get this
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx

Comment: I doubt you've managed to break LibreOffice just by using sudo in the wrong place. Open a new question to get someone to help you fix LibreOffice.

Comment: Also, please click the tick next to this question to accept it as it's correct.